# Smaller \frametitle row in Hannover theme in beamer

Tags: beamer, spacing, frame-title

[image]

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usecolortheme{default}
\usetheme[width=2.3cm]{Hannover} 

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{abc abc}
    \blindtext
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Does anyone know how to shift frame titles towards the top hand right corner of the slide, increasing also the body area of slides?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this ?

[image]

```
\documentclass[t,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usecolortheme{default}
\usetheme[width=2.3cm]{Hannover} 

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{
\hfill
\insertframetitle}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{abc abc}
    \blindtext
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @AndreFC You are welcome!  Pleased to know that your problem is solved.